# Logistic regression to predict a buy

Tags: machine-learning, regression, apache-spark-mllib, logistic-regression, predict

I have 3 years data of international importers buying raw materials from various countries. Data consists of:

Product code, Buyer Country, Buyer Name, Destination port, Seller Country, Seller Name, Origin port, unit, Value(USD), Unit Price.

I would like to predict if a particular buyer will be looking to make a buy transaction in the next week. Logistic regression came as a natural choice for this. However, looking at the data it only has positive outcomes, should I balance the data for having both positive and negative outcomes?

So if I am looking at a weekly prediction, should I aggregate all of that buyer's transaction for a week and add a negative outcome row in whichever week there has not been a transaction?

Comment: Would really appreciate a comment for downvote as I am very new to this area and am willing to correct or edit any inadequacies in the question.

Comment: Probably because this belongs to CrossValidated since it has little to do with programming.

Comment: @user2974951 My question is actually about the approach, am I right by adding those aggregated non-buy rows. Crossvalidation is something that comes later, innit?

Answer (score 1):

Right now this is very abstract and so only abstract answers can be given.

Pretty much any binary model requires both classes to be present in the training data set, so you need to gather more data to contain both classes (or split them further to make finer intervals which will contain both classes, if that is what you are alluding to).

Cross Validation is done at the same time as model building to assess the performance of the model.